# javafx focus window

Tags: java, user-interface, focus, javafx, javafx-2

when I start in NetBeans my JavaFX game and after display game window I clicked somewere outside this window, after I can not focus this game window. I can focus the game window only when I immediately clicked on game window after display game window. How I can set focusable that I can focus game window any time?
Thanks.

Comment: can you, please, elaborate? Provide code where you creates window. And what do you mean by "I can not focus this game window" -- you click on window title and nothing happens?

Comment: Sorry,I solved this problem already..

Comment: If you solve the problem, we encourage you to post your solution as an answer and click the check mark to the left of it, to indicate what worked for you. It helps future users with the same problem, and gives you an opportunity to give back to the community in a constructive manner.

Answer (score 9):

This is done through [`Stage.requestFocus()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#requestFocus%28%29).

Comment: and how to in FXML?